# Alternative to Wubi Installer (without cd/usb install)

Tags: lubuntu, wubi, system-installation

I'm using a old computer and I'm interested in getting linux on it.

My computer cannot boot from USB or CD. I was presented with  Wubi but I was just wondering, is there any other way to install Ubuntu (or actually, xubuntu or lubuntu) on my computer without having to manually repartition and stuff. Like have the normal cd/usb install but without a cd/usb

(P.S. I don't need to dual boot windows and linux)

Comment: what do you have in that system? do you have utp? here is a method installing over UTP: http://polishlinux.org/installation/installing-linux-over-network-no-cd-drive/

Comment: uhhh i do but main problem is I don't have another computer that has any distro of linux installed on it

Comment: How much RAM has your computer got?

Comment: @user268805 but you do have a 2nd computer? If so creating a dual boot there and then do a pixie install might work (ie. install over utp).

Comment: When you say really old - Can you give us some idea of the specification: RAM hard disk size etc. If you can't boot from CD what can you boot from?

Comment: another option: you can install Linux from grub too (requires you to put the ISO on the harddisc).

Comment: uhhhhh no second computer, and it's 1.3ghz dual core (but that's bs it's much slower than that), 4GB DDR3 RAM, integrated graphics (as expected), HDD amazingly 500GB. Can't boot from cd can't boot from sub can do network boot i guess

Answer (score 0):

No, there are only 2 paths you can follow:

1. Boot from CD and install alongside Windows
2. Install through Wubi

There are other paths (for example, run install from network) but I doubt they will work in your case. If you don't need dual-boot, install through Wubi. But I suggest you to install alongside.

This topic describes how to boot from CD on old computer: [How to boot from CD even if BIOS doesn't allow this](https://superuser.com/questions/735729/how-to-boot-from-cd-even-if-bios-doesnt-allow-this).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Wubi is Windows thing to install Ubuntu over existing Windows. It senses that you have Windows on your PC already. I thought you might have no OS.
If so, then:
There are some ways to actually do the required tasks, you may follow any of below:

1. You plug out your PC HD and attach it to another PC and install Ubuntu over there.
2. Plug out HD and use HD to USB converter, which is a tool which changes your HD to external USB hard drive. and install Ubuntu over the HD with another PC or netcafe, public PC. [hehe i actually do that in my hometown xD].
3. You have wubi concept you can also use Wubi to install Ubuntu [which i do not know how! hehe. :p]
4. You can use external CD-DVD rom [mouse pin type not USB] and install via it.
5. You may use a tool which converts USB to PIN type tool [old PC's come with 5 holes PIN input for MOUSE , keyboards.hehe xD ] and install Ubuntu via USB.